# オフトピックかの判断: プログラマに関する英語の質問について

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

[「外向的な計算機科学者」の解釈](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2431/%E5%A4%96%E5%90%91%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97%E6%A9%9F%E7%A7%91%E5%AD%A6%E8%80%85-%E3%81%AE%E8%A7%A3%E9%87%88)という英語のジョークの解釈の質問があるのですが、ヘルプセンターのこれは[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)のこの場で質問するのにふさわしい例に含まれないと考えています。

このような、英語の解釈の質問は日本のスタックオーバーフローでは良いのでしょうか？

<strike>自分の意見では、この質問は英語の解釈は主観が入る上、英語に関する質問だと思うのでオフトピックだと考えています。</strike>

**追記**

皆さんの回答を受けて、ちょっと考えが変わりました。
例が良くなかった(結果的に知識が必要なかったというのも含め)ですね。

プログラミング等の知識が必要な他言語の解釈の質問は、確実に必要となると思っています。
ただ、線引きが問題だと自分は思っています。どこまでを対象にするのかという所ですね。

この辺りは線を引いても仕方がないかなとは思ってるので、entoさんの考えに賛成しています。

結論を言うと、自分の今の意見ではヘルプセンターの文章を変えて、他言語の解釈の質問を受けるようにすべきだと考えています。

Comment: 現在のルールを考えなかったとして、rizaudoさんがどう思うかも添えた方がいいんじゃないでしょうか。（コミュニティが良いと思えばルールが変わることもあるそうです。全部ではないですが。）

Comment: @fliedonion なるほど、自分はルールを考えないとしても良くないと思っているので、少し意見を書いてみたいと思います。

Comment: 現在のスコアは-2になっているため、評判が良くないです。とりあえず、このような質問は不適切と思ったら、マイナス票をしてくれたら助かります。

Answer (score 2):

「プログラミングに関連する知識が必要な問題ではないか?」と考えて、英語に関する質問を投稿することは問題ないと思います。

その結果、技術分野と関わりの薄い英語圏の知識を必要とする質問であると分かったら、クローズしてよいと思います。クローズするのは、「ここは第一にプログラミングに関する知識・知見を持った人の集まりなので、英語に関する問題を持ち込むのは注意が必要」ということを後から質問を見た人に知らせるため、という意味合いが大きいと思っています。

例として、 「[Appleの規約が更新されて `14. Personal attacks` 部分がよくわかりません。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/509/30)」は英語に関する質問ですが、プログラミング稼業に関わる内容なので、問題ないと受け止められていると思います。

Answer (score 1):

英語版ですと Programmers や English Language & Usage がありますのでオフトピックなのは確実ですが日本語版ではどうなのでしょうか。

私がここに質問を投稿したのは、何らかのプログラミングに関する文化的背景を理解していないと正確に解釈することができないのではないかという懸念があったからです。元の英語版に投稿されていたジョークはプログラマーでないと理解しにくいジョークばかりのはずです。
単なる英文の解釈の質問であればここには投稿しません。結果的にはそこまで深い意味はなかったようなので、英語の質問になってしまっていますが。

ジョークの解釈が主観的であるという意見には賛成しかねます。ジョークというものはある程度の共通の解釈があってこそ成立するもののはずです。それに、英語の解釈が主観的で答えが決定できないと仮定すると、例えば語学試験の採点など不可能になってしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

自分は**悪い質問ではない**と思います。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke

**訳は単なる変換作業だ**と考えることができるからです。
変換の作業に疑問を生じたのなら答えは一つに定まります。
説明に主観は含まれますが答え自体は主観ではありません。
**答えを証明するための主観ほどでしか無い**のです。

しかも、答えが、
あなたが外を歩くプログラマーなら外向的プログラマで、外出しないのなら内向的、それはあなたの靴を見なさいというだけです。

考え方によっては日本語版スタックオーバーフローは質問を制限しすぎていると思います。
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=Joke

Comment: 最後のリンクについて: "joke"関連の制限具合を比較するには[クローズもロックもされていない質問も検索する](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=joke%20closed%3a0%20locked%3a0%20is%3aquestion)とよいと思います。さらに、[タイトルに"joke"が含まれている場合に限定](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Ajoke+closed%3A0+locked%3A0+is%3Aquestion)することもできます。